# Mt. 18:5 or 19:14 to argue against contraception?

Tags: catholicism, gospel-of-matthew, marriage, children, contraception

Have any Catholic theologians, Doctors, or Fathers of the Church used

> [Mt. 18:5](http://drbo.org/cgi-bin/d?b=drl&bk=47&ch=18&l=5-#x)
> he that shall receive one such little child in my name, receiveth me.

or especially

> [Mt. 19:14](http://drbo.org/cgi-bin/d?b=drl&bk=47&ch=19&l=14-#x)
> Suffer the little children, and forbid them not to come to me: for the kingdom of heaven is for such.

to argue against contraception?

Comment: On the assumption you're asking because some use those verses to argue against contraception, could you articulate how either of those verses are referencing unborn children or otherwise arguing against contraception.  Matt. 19:14 is saying not to forbid Children from accepting Christ as their savior, is it not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although not a theologian, Mother Teresa of Calcutta in [her speech to the National Prayer Breakfast, Washington, DC, February 3, 1994](https://www.priestsforlife.org/library/4386-whatsoever-you-do) (video @[19:30](https://youtu.be/OXn-wf5ylgo?t=1170)) makes the connection:

> I never give a child to a couple who has done something not to have a child.* Jesus said: "Anyone who receives a child in my name, receives me." [[Mt. 18:5](http://drbo.org/cgi-bin/d?b=drl&bk=47&ch=18&l=5-#x)]

<sup>*e.g., by contraception, which she mentions beginning @[20:14](https://youtu.be/OXn-wf5ylgo?t=1214)</sup>

Comment: > But Jesus turned to them and said, “Daughters of Jerusalem, do not weep for me, but weep for yourselves and for your children.   For the days are surely coming when they will say, ‘Blessed are the barren, and the wombs that never bore, and the breasts that never nursed. (Lk 23: 28-29). Yes , Jesus  did foresee  that children would one day be less welcome than they used to be